# Customizing css on an iframe

Tags: css, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

I am using a carousel to display a YouTube video using an `<iframe />`. The problem is that I want to customize the CSS of the code inside the `<iframe />`. I tried to force my CSS, it didn't work, I tried to add CSS attributes by JavaScript, but it is not possible for any properties to be taken into account. Is it possible by another way?

Comment: If the page being loaded in the `<iframe />` is on a different domain then it's out of your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SRC of the iFrame has a different source or protocol (http://, https://), then you can not access it at all with anything. If it is the same source and protocol, then I've had no problems in the past using `jQueryObject.content().find('#ObjectID').css()` in the past